Trying to prove $U$ implements a logical $CCZ$ gate on the $[[8,3,2]]$ code?
I know from several different papers that the gate $U=TT^{\dagger}TT^{\dagger}TT^{\dagger}TT^{\dagger}$ actually implements a logical $CCZ$ gate on the $[[8,3,2]]$ quantum code. However, I am having difficulty proving this to myself.
My understanding is that $UX_{L_{i}}U^{\dagger}$ should have the same effect on $X_{L_{i}}$ as $CCZX_{i}CCZ^{\dagger}$ has on $X_{i}$ (in order for $U$ to implement a logical $CCZ$).
However, I cannot figure this out as I know that $X_{L_{1}} = X \otimes X \otimes X \otimes X \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I$ and $$U: X_{L_{1}} \rightarrow SX \otimes S^{\dagger}X \otimes SX \otimes S^{\dagger}X \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I.$$
Whereas $X_{1} = X \otimes I \otimes I$ and $$CCZ: X \otimes I \otimes I \rightarrow X \otimes CZ_{2,3} = X \otimes |0\rangle\langle0| \otimes I + X \otimes |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes Z.$$
However, I do not see from the above workings how $U$ has the same effect on $X_{L_{1}}$ as $CCZ$ has on $X_{1}$?

This might be one of the rare cases where writing down the action on kets is more expedient than working in the stabilizer language.

You are almost there, you just lack some information about the $[[8, 3, 2]]$ code. Your goal is to prove that the $X_i$ logical operator is mapped to the $X_i C_{j,k}$ logical operator, which requires you to know how to perform such a $C_{j,k}$. Consulting this code's error correction zoo page, logical $CZ$ gates seems to have a transversal implementation, found out by this paper.
An alternating pattern of $S$ and $S^\dagger$ gates on the qubits of a face of the cube translates to a $CZ$ gate between the two logical qubits whose logical $X$ is not supported on this face. This is exactly what your computation leads you to.
It might be worth noting that $XS \otimes XS^{\dagger} \otimes XS \otimes XS^{\dagger} \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I$ and $SX \otimes S^{\dagger}X \otimes SX \otimes S^{\dagger}X \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I \otimes I$ denotes the same logical operator because they only differ by a stabilizer: the $Z$-stabilizer over the $[1,2,3,4]$ face. This essentially tells you that $X_{1}C_{2,3} = C_{2,3}X_{1}$ which is reassuring.
